# Lan viruses propagation tecnics

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems, lan, tcp

i'm a newbie in lan/sys administration. I would like to understand how viruses infect local 
 area network and what tecnics hacker use to propagate them.
I want to develop my own simple software to prevent LAN viruses to propagate.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: viruses are a cat and mouse game, you against the virus writer.  You must think of everything that every virus writer, ever, has thought of, plus all the things they will think of in the future.  (If you are a virus writer, you must think of everything an anti-virus writer has written, and do something they're not expecting.)  There is no simple software to prevent virus propagation, because viruses are not simple.

If you are a brand new sysadmin, you do not have the experience to write the software you need, full stop.  Buy anti-virus software from a reputable company (or even use some of the excellent free ones that are available, if you're strapped for cash).  Your users will thank you.

The only reason to learn about how viruses work and propagate at a level deep enough to write software is either because a: you work for an anti-virus company, or b: you want to write them yourself.  Naturally I would have no desire to help anyone with the latter, and if the former is true, your coworkers can surely point you to resources.

However, as a new sysadmin, you should *definitely* learn about security, and there's a lot more to security than anti-virus software.  Consider taking one of the free Coursera course on networks and security to boot strap yourself:
https://www.coursera.org/courses?cats=cs-systems  I'd recommend the one by Dan Boneh, but there aren't any open sessions at the moment.  There's also an excellent book by Ross Anderson, which he has graciously made available for free online: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/book.html

It's not enough, but it will hopefully show you where the gaps in your knowledge are, so you can guide your self-study effectively.

Happy securing!